# Hadoop 2.6.1 java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.isLazyPersist(DFSOutputStream.java:1709)

Tags: java, hadoop

When i try to append to a File in HDFS, i get exception as below. Please advise

```
file.append(new Path(uri));
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.isLazyPersist(DFSOutputStream.java:1709)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.getChecksum4Compute(DFSOutputStream.java:1550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.<init>(DFSOutputStream.java:1560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.<init>(DFSOutputStream.java:1667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForAppend(DFSOutputStream.java:1694)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callAppend(DFSClient.java:1824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.append(DFSClient.java:1885)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.append(DFSClient.java:1855)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$4.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$4.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.append(DistributedFileSystem.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.append(DistributedFileSystem.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.append(FileSystem.java:1164)
```

Please note that I have this issue only with Hadoop version **2.6.1** but it's working fine with version **2.7.1**

Comment: for some reason, HdfsFileStatus is null. Please check [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.7.0/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/DFSOutputStream.java#DFSOutputStream.isLazyPersist%28org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.HdfsFileStatus%29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Problem was with version of apache hadoop client jar. In my pom.xml, I had the latest version 2.7.1 which to my surprise is incompatible with hadoop 2.6.1 installation.**There is no backward compatibility for hadoop client jar.** Final change to my pom.xml is as below

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
<dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to version conflict. try changing dependency in xml file